# como fazer o VBA interagir com mais de uma aba no Internet Explorer?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

Tenho uma macro em VBA que manipula o Internet Explorer, em certo momento ao clicar em um item, uma nova aba é aberta no Internet Explorer.

Minha duvida é: **como mudar o foco do VBA para manipular essa nova aba que foi aberta?**

segue código:

```
Sub x()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://www.comprasgovernamentais.gov.br/acesso-aos-sistemas/comprasnet-siasg"
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set objCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    i = 0
    n = objCollection.Length
    Do While i < n
        If objCollection(i).href = "https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/seguro/loginPortal.asp" Then
           objCollection(i).Click
           i = n
           Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
           Loop
           Sleep (3000)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ie.Document.getElementById("perfil").Item(2).Selected = True
    ie.Document.getElementById("perfil").fireEvent "onchange"
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    Sleep (3000)
    ie.Document.getElementById("txtLogin").Value = "xxxxxxx"
    ie.Document.getElementById("txtSenha").Value = "xxxxxxx"
    ie.Document.getElementById("acessar").Click
    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    Sleep (3000)

    Set objCollection = ie.Document.frames(1).Document.getElementsByTagName("div")
    i = 0
    n = objCollection.Length
    Do While i < n
        If objCollection(i).innertext = "IRP" Then
            objCollection(i).fireEvent "onclick" 'após disparar este evento a nova aba é aberta
            i = n
            Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            Loop
            Sleep (3000)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui! o código a seguir vai de aba em aba do IE e testa se o elemento desejado esta na pagina e se a URL é igual a desejada

```
sub x()
     CapturaTela (irpNr)

end sub

Public Sub CapturaTela(irpNr As String)
    Dim url As String, NrSei As String
    Dim element As Object
    Dim cont As Integer
    cont = 1
    Set IE = Get_IE_Window2(irpNr)
End Sub

Private Function Get_IE_Window2(irpNr As String) As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim Shell As Object
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim NrSei As Integer
    Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    i = 0
    Set Get_IE_Window2 = Nothing

    While i < Shell.Windows.Count And Get_IE_Window2 Is Nothing
        Set IE = Shell.Windows.Item(i) 'coloca o foco na janela "i" do IE
        If Not IE Is Nothing Then
            If InStr(IE.LocationURL, "https://www2.comprasnet.gov.br/siasgnet-irp") > 0 Then 'testa se a URL é a certa
                For Each element In IE.Document.getElementsBytagname("input")
                If element.name = "irp.numeroIrpFormatado" And element.Value = irpNr Then 'testa se o elemento desejado esta na pagina
                    NrSei = 100
                    Exit For 'achou a pagina procurada, sai do laço
                End If
                Next
            End If
            If Not IE Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print IE.LocationURL, IE.LocationName
                If TypeName(IE) = "IWebBrowser2" Then 'verifica se é um webBrowser
                    If TypeOf IE Is SHDocVw.InternetExplorer And IE.LocationURL <> "" And NrSei > 0 Then 'testa se a url é nula, e se o elemento foi achado
                        Set Get_IE_Window2 = IE
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Else: i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Function
```